# Bijection $f: N_n\to N_m$

Tags: functions, reference-request

Let $N_n=\{ 1,2,...,n\}$ and $N_m=\{1,2,...,m\}$, if $n\neq m$, then it doesn't exist $f:N_n \to N_m$ such that $f$ is a bijection.

According to my teacher this proof is complicated, but I would like to know how to do it, does anyone know in which text I can find it?

Edit:

In this proof

Let $A$ be a finite and nonempty set.  Let $m, n$ be positive integers and suppose that $f: N_n \to A$ and $g: N_m \to A$ are bijections.  So $m = n$.

Proof:

The inverse of the function $g^{-1}: A\to N_m$ is bijective. we can affirm that the composition $g^{-1}\circ  f : N_n \to N_m$  is a bijection.  This contradicts  the above statement, then $m=n$.

Comment: One of you is lying. There is nothing complicated about this.

Comment: An intuitive proof is easy, but a formal proof? @JohnDouma

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Formally, how do you define cardinality? To me, A bijection from $N_m$ is precisely how we say a set has $m$ elements. Even without referring to cardinality, by the definition of a function, each element can be mapped to at most one element so a set with $m$ elements  ...

Comment: But you have to prove that this definition actually works. That is, you have to prove that if the cardinality of $X$ is equal to the cardinalities of $N_n$ and $N_m,$ then $n=m.$ That is intuitive, but it requires some work - in the very least, it requires a more precise definition of $\{1,2,\dots,n\},$ and then some proof. @JohnDouma

Comment: What is described above as "In this proof" is an application of the proposition stated at the beginning of the body of your Question.  It relies on that proposition to demonstrate something, rather than serving as a proof of it.  Of course a real proof would require definitions for the natural numbers and the initial segment $N_m,N_n$.  I'm not clear what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Zuy answer I was able to find a good proof in "The Art of Proof" by Matthias Beck-Ross Geoghegan. I share them below

Lemma 1: If $f: A\to B$ is a bijection and $a\in A$, define de new function $f':A\setminus\{a\}\to B\setminus\{f(a)\}$ by $f'(x):=f(x)$. Then $f'$ is well defined and bijective.

Lemma 2: If $1\leq k\leq n$ then the function $g_k: N_{n-1}\to N_n\setminus\{k\}$ defined by

$
  g_k(j) = 
  \left \{
    \begin{aligned}
      j &,\ \text{if} \ j<k\\
      j+1 &,\ \text{if} \ j\geq k
    \end{aligned}
  \right .
$

is a bijection.

Now if we proceed to test the main result

Theorem: Let $m\neq n$ there exists no bijection $N_m\to N_n$.

Proof:

We prove the statement $P(m)$ (induction): For all $n\neq m$ there exists no bijection $N_n\to N_m$.
For the induction step, let $m\geq 2$ and assume we know that $P(m-1)$ is true. Suppose there exists a bijection $f:N_m\to N_n$ for some $n\neq m$. Let $k=f(m)$ and define, as in Lemma 1 $f':N_{m-1}\to N_n\setminus\{k\}$ by $f'(x):=f(x)$. Lemma 1 says that this  new function is also bijective. The composition os $f'$ with the inverse of the function $g_k$ defined in Lemma 2 gives a bijection $N_{m-1}\to N_{n-1}$. But this contradicts our induction hypotesis.

Answer (score 1):

We start by proving the following.

**Lemma:** If $f:N_n\to S$ for some $S\subsetneq N_n$, then $f$ is not injective.

*Proof.* We proceed by induction on $n\geq 0$. If $n=0$, then $N_n=\varnothing$, and the Lemma is vacuously true. Next, assume that the assertion holds for some $n$; we prove it for $n+1$. So let $f:N_{n+1}\to S$ be a map and $S\subsetneq N_{n+1}.$ First, assume $n+1\not\in S$. Then $S\subsetneq N_n$ and $f|_{N_n}:N_n\to S$ isn't injective by induction hypothesis, so $f$ is neither. Next, assume $n+1\in S$. Then $n+1=f(m)$ for some $m\in N_{n+1}$. Seeking for a contradiction, assume that $f$ is injective. Define a function $g:N_n\to S-\{n+1\}$ by $g(m)=f(n+1)$ (in case $m\neq n+1$) and $g(k)=f(k)$ for $k\neq m$. Clearly, $g$ is injective, contradicting the induction hypothesis. This completes the proof.$\quad\tiny\blacksquare$

Now, let's see why this implies your result. Assume for a moment that there was a bijection $f:N_n\to N_m$ for some $n\neq m$. Then we may assume $n>m$ (else, consider $f^{-1}$). The Lemma now states that $f$ cannot be injective, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I have been able to write a proof according to my course, I thank you, in a few minutes I will write the proof here

Answer (score -2):

This isn't hard. Note that if $A, B$ are finite sets, then

- $|A|\leq |B|$ if an injection $f:A\to B$ exists;
- $|A|\geq |B|$ if a surjection $f:A\to B$ exists.

Thus, if $f:A\to B$ is a bijection, it holds that $|A|=|B|$. This should suffice to answer your question by yourself.

Comment: This assumes a *lot* about cardinality. This is true, but the results you have used also require proof.

Comment: this seems to me more like a proof of the bijection principle

Comment: You can use the pigeonhole principle without actually referring to it. What happens if $m\lt n$? Each element of $N_m$ can be mapped to how many elements? How many is that in total? Is that enough?

Comment: The pigeonhole principal also requires proof. It is essentially equivalent. @JohnDouma

Comment: @ThomasAndrews But we don't have to refer to it. We can argue that $f$ can only take at most $m$ values so there will be missing values in the codomain.

Comment: @JohnDouma How are you going to make that formal? This is why the proof is way more complicated than the intuition. Intuitively, pigeonhole makes sense, but proving it requires a lot of foundational work.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Since formal proofs involve axioms and inference rules, all formal proofs are difficult to write. There is nothing in the original post about a formal proof. Saying that a set with $m$ elements can only be mapped to $m$ elements is a matter of counting which is rigorous if not formal.

Comment: Presumably, given that a professor said it was complicated, the professor was probably thinking of a more foundation proof, rather than an informal proof. For example, where the natural numbers are represented by ordinals and the like. @JohnDouma

Comment: @ThomasAndrews This is probably terrible of me to even think but it is also possible that someone gets stuck on a problem and says "my professor said this is too complicated to solve" and one of us says, no, you just have to do this.